# My GUI isn't working for my for my text based adventure game, the code runs but the choice buttons i made don't work. Why? Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to make a text based adventure game with a GUI and it was all going well until I got stuck a part where my start button works but my choice buttons won't work. I am following a YouTube tutorial(https://youtu.be/j99EeUjvLVQ) and got stuck at around 10:00 can someone help? here's my code:

I am almost positive that my problem is somewhere inside my Story and Game classes but I included the rest just in case. I'm using Eclipse if that helps at all.

````
```
package package01;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Game {

ChoiceHandler cHandler = new ChoiceHandler();
UI ui = new UI();
VisibilityManager vm = new VisibilityManager(ui);
Story story = new Story(this,ui,vm);

String nextPosition1, nextPosition2, nextPosition3, nextPosition4;

public static void main(String[] args) {

   new Game();

}
public Game() {
   ui.makeUI(cHandler);
   story.defaultSetup();
   vm.showTitleScreen();

}


public class ChoiceHandler implements ActionListener{

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

       String yourChoice = event.getActionCommand();

       switch(yourChoice) {
       case"Start": vm.TitleToStart(); story.WasteLand(); break;
       case "c1": story.selectPosition(nextPosition1);break;
       case "c2": story.selectPosition(nextPosition2);break;
       case "c3": story.selectPosition(nextPosition3); break;
       case "c4": story.selectPosition(nextPosition4); break;          
   }       
   }   
   } 
   }

```
package package01;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import package01.Game.ChoiceHandler;


public class UI {

JFrame window;
JPanel titleNamePanel, startButtonPanel, mainTextPanel, choiceButtonPanel, playerPanel;
JLabel titleNameLabel, hpLabel, hpLabelNumber, weaponLabel, weaponLabelName;
JButton startButton, choice1,choice2,choice3,choice4;
JTextArea mainTextArea;
Font titleFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 90);
Font normalFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 28);


public void makeUI(ChoiceHandler cHandler) {

//WINDOW
   window = new JFrame();
   window.setSize(800, 600);
   window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
   window.setLayout(null);



//TITLE
   titleNamePanel = new JPanel();
   titleNamePanel.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 150);
   titleNamePanel.setBackground(Color.black);
   titleNameLabel = new JLabel("ADVENTURE");
   titleNameLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
   titleNameLabel.setFont(titleFont);  
   titleNamePanel.add(titleNameLabel);


   startButtonPanel = new JPanel();
   startButtonPanel.setBounds(300, 400, 200, 100);
   startButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
   startButton = new JButton("START");
   startButton.setBackground(Color.black);
   startButton.setForeground(Color.white);
   startButton.setFont(normalFont);
   startButton.setFocusPainted(false);
   startButton.addActionListener(cHandler);
   startButton.setActionCommand("Start");
   startButtonPanel.add(startButton);
   window.add(titleNamePanel);
   window.add(startButtonPanel);



   //GAME SCREEN
   mainTextPanel = new JPanel();
   mainTextPanel.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 250);
   mainTextPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
   window.add(mainTextPanel);

   mainTextArea = new JTextArea();
   mainTextArea.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 250);
   mainTextArea.setBackground(Color.black);
   mainTextArea.setForeground(Color.white);
   mainTextArea.setFont(normalFont);
   mainTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
   mainTextPanel.add(mainTextArea);

   choiceButtonPanel = new JPanel();
   choiceButtonPanel.setBounds(250, 350, 300, 150);
   choiceButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
   choiceButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
   window.add(choiceButtonPanel);

   choice1 = new JButton("Choice 1");
   choice1.setBackground(Color.black);
   choice1.setForeground(Color.white);
   choice1.setFont(normalFont);
   choice1.setFocusPainted(false);
   choice1.addActionListener(cHandler);
   choice1.setActionCommand("c1");
   choiceButtonPanel.add(choice1);

   choice2 = new JButton("Choice 2");
   choice2.setBackground(Color.black);
   choice2.setForeground(Color.white);
   choice2.setFont(normalFont);
   choice2.setFocusPainted(false);
   choice1.addActionListener(cHandler);
   choice2.setActionCommand("c2");
   choiceButtonPanel.add(choice2);

   choice3 = new JButton("Choice 3");
   choice3.setBackground(Color.black);
   choice3.setForeground(Color.white);
   choice3.setFont(normalFont);
   choice3.setFocusPainted(false);
   choice1.addActionListener(cHandler);
   choice3.setActionCommand("c3");
   choiceButtonPanel.add(choice3);

   choice4 = new JButton("Choice 4");
   choice4.setBackground(Color.black);
   choice4.setForeground(Color.white);
   choice4.setFont(normalFont);
   choice4.setFocusPainted(false);
   choice1.addActionListener(cHandler);
   choice4.setActionCommand("c4");
   choiceButtonPanel.add(choice4);


   playerPanel = new JPanel();
   playerPanel.setBounds(100, 15, 600, 50);
   playerPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
   playerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
   window.add(playerPanel);

   hpLabel = new JLabel("HP:");
   hpLabel.setFont(normalFont);
   hpLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
   playerPanel.add(hpLabel);
   hpLabelNumber = new JLabel();
   hpLabelNumber.setFont(normalFont);
   hpLabelNumber.setForeground(Color.white);
   playerPanel.add(hpLabelNumber);

   weaponLabel = new JLabel("Weapon:");
   weaponLabel.setFont(normalFont);
   weaponLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
   playerPanel.add(weaponLabel);
   weaponLabelName = new JLabel();
   weaponLabelName.setFont(normalFont);
   weaponLabelName.setForeground(Color.white);
   playerPanel.add(weaponLabelName);


   window.setVisible(true);    
}

}
````

````
package package01;

public class VisibilityManager {
UI ui;
public VisibilityManager(UI userInterface) {

    ui = userInterface;
 }

public void showTitleScreen() {

    //Show the title screen
    ui.titleNamePanel.setVisible(true);
    ui.startButtonPanel.setVisible(true);


    //Hide the game screen
    ui.mainTextPanel.setVisible(false);
    ui.choiceButtonPanel.setVisible(false);
    ui.playerPanel.setVisible(false);


  }
  public void TitleToStart() {

    //hide title screen
    ui.titleNamePanel.setVisible(false);
    ui.startButtonPanel.setVisible(false);

    //show game screen
    ui.mainTextPanel.setVisible(true);
    ui.choiceButtonPanel.setVisible(true);
    ui.playerPanel.setVisible(true);




  }   
  }
  ```
 package package01;

 public class VisibilityManager {
 UI ui;
 public VisibilityManager(UI userInterface) {

    ui = userInterface;
 }

 public void showTitleScreen() {

    //Show the title screen
    ui.titleNamePanel.setVisible(true);
    ui.startButtonPanel.setVisible(true);


    //Hide the game screen
    ui.mainTextPanel.setVisible(false);
    ui.choiceButtonPanel.setVisible(false);
    ui.playerPanel.setVisible(false);


    }
   public void TitleToStart() {

    //hide title screen
    ui.titleNamePanel.setVisible(false);
    ui.startButtonPanel.setVisible(false);

    //show game screen
    ui.mainTextPanel.setVisible(true);
    ui.choiceButtonPanel.setVisible(true);
    ui.playerPanel.setVisible(true);




  }  
}
````

Comment: Why set choice1.setActionListner to cHandler so many times?

Comment: *"I am following a YouTube tutorial"* - Personally, I'd avoid it - it doesn't seem to be providing you many good ideas

Comment: oh my god you solved my problem. I copy and pasted without checking it. Thanks!